# Razor Pages Display Validation for Hidden Input

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am attempting to provide user friendly input (as a percentage) for a decimal and be able to validate. I am stuck because the asp-validation-for will not display if the associated input is hidden.

Current technique is to use autonumeric.js for the client side formatting on a display only field that gets copied into the field to be saved to db.

How can I get validation message to display?

**LoanEstimate.cs**

```
[NotMapped]
public string RateDisplayOnly { get; set; }

[Range(0,1,ErrorMessage="Rate must be between 0.000% and 100.00%")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:p}")]
[Required]
public decimal? Rate { get; set; }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LoanEstimate.Rate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="LoanEstimate.RateDisplayOnly" class="form-control autonumeric-display-only autonumeric-percent" />
        <input asp-for="LoanEstimate.Rate" class="form-control" type="hidden"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="LoanEstimate.Rate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    //autonumeric.js field formatting
    const anElement = AutoNumeric.multiple('.autonumeric-currency', {
        currencySymbol: "$"
    });

    const anElement2 = AutoNumeric.multiple('.autonumeric-percent', {
            decimalPlaces: 3,
            rawValueDivisor: 100,
            suffixText: "%"
        }
    )
    $(".autonumeric-display-only").on('keyup', function () {
        var str = this.id
        var getThis = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("DisplayOnly"))
        $("#" + getThis).val(AutoNumeric.getNumericString("#" + this.id));
    });
    
});
```

**Problem**

Validation message does not display when input for LoanEstimate.Rate is hidden

[image]

Note: here is it displaying properly when not hidden
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.validator.setDefaults`,here is a demo:

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Rate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="RateDisplayOnly" class="form-control autonumeric-display-only autonumeric-percent" onblur="validateRate()"/>
        <input asp-for="Rate" class="form-control" hidden />
        <span asp-validation-for="Rate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
function validateRate() {
        $("#Rate").valid();
    }
$.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: [],
            // other default options
        });
        $(document).ready(function ($) {

            //autonumeric.js field formatting
            const anElement = AutoNumeric.multiple('.autonumeric-currency', {
                currencySymbol: "$"
            });

            const anElement2 = AutoNumeric.multiple('.autonumeric-percent', {
                decimalPlaces: 3,
                rawValueDivisor: 100,
                suffixText: "%"
            }
            )
            $(".autonumeric-display-only").on('keyup', function () {
                var str = this.id
                var getThis = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("DisplayOnly"))
                $("#" + getThis).val(AutoNumeric.getNumericString("#" + this.id));
            });

        });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! The message is indeed triggered upon pressing submit. I notice that when the input field is not hidden, the validation message triggers when I tab out of the field <input asp-for="Rate" class="form-control" />, however with this method it only triggers upon pressing submit. Is there a way to get it to trigger when I tab out of <input asp-for="RateDisplayOnly" class="form-control autonumeric-display-only autonumeric-percent" />?

Comment: I have updated my answer,add onblur function on `<input asp-for="RateDisplayOnly"/>`,when the element lost focus,validate $("#Rate").

Comment: Awesome! Your suggestion in the comment above works, note: the code sample you have in your answer doesn't though. Please replace with something like             $(".autonumeric-display-only").blur(function () {
                var str = this.id
                var getThis = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("DisplayOnly"))
                $("#" + getThis).valid();
            }); (inside of document ready I believe)and I will mark as answer. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ah but your example works with your code, so it's good to go, marking as answer, thanks!